# objective-c the upload image on the server is incompleted

Tags: php, objective-c, apache2, jpeg

I am maintaining some code that upload photos from an ipad onto apache2 server via objective-c and php. In objective-c the picture is updated using AFNetworking POST function. The picture actually is being uploaded successfully, however it is incomplete. Here is what I get on the server:
[image]

As you can see it only shows the top left part of the screenshot. 
The code in objective-c is something like these for imagePickerController

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    LoginData * dataObject = [self dataObject];
    NSString *tempPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"upload-image.jpg"];
    NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:tempPath];

    UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1);
    [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    NSString *uploaddir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"../exampledir/"];
    NSString *requestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/handle_upload.php", httpPath];
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:path, @"newname",uploaddir, @"pathname", nil];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:requestURL parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"uploadedfile" fileName:path mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]
          initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Upload was successful" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error with upload : %@", error);
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]
          initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Upload was completed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
    }];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

and the file "handle_upload.php" is as followed:

```
<?php
require_once("validate.php");

/* This script uploads a file to a given directory with a given name
 * Parameters:
 * @pathname - the path of the directory the file will be uploaded to
 * @newname - the new name of the file
 * @uploadedfile - the file to be uploaded
 */

$target_path = $_POST['pathname'];
$new_name = $_POST['newname'];


$target_path = $target_path . basename($new_name);

if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] > 0) {
    echo "There was an error transferring the file" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Error code: " . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] . PHP_EOL;
}
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file " . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) .
                     " has been uploaded";   // success is indicated by presence of string 'has been uploaded'
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!" . PHP_EOL;
    echo '$_POST[\'pathname\']: ' . $_POST['pathname'] . ' $_POST[\'newname\']: ' . $_POST['newname'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo '$target_path: ' . $target_path . PHP_EOL;

    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"] . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] / 1024) . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"] . PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

Have anyone every meet this kind of problem before? I will be really appreciate to any help even just some direction to solve this problem.

Comment: wtf, so your uploaded image gets somehow cropped?

Comment: orz. I am not sure whether it is due to image cropped or cut by some certain settings inside program or on server. That is why I am here asking for help. Anyway the screenshot on device itself is fine.

Comment: no it wont be the server, I bet it is sent cropped from the app, why are you using `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`

Comment: use `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`

Comment: I see. You are right. That should be a dumb mistake. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` to `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`